# Parsing a wrapped CSV file with only one pass over line string

Tags: c++, string, csv, c++20

I want to try and find a very fast way of parsing a csv file which has its field wrapped by double-qoutes.

As you see in the code I have some test cases.

The problems I have:

- How to reliably tell if we are at the end of the line and there will be no `comma` after last closing wrapper character
- how to deal with whitespace between end of one field and start of next
- inside a field two double-quotes (or any wrapper char of choice) means I should count that as part of the resulting string

Here is where I have given up (also on compiler explorer https://godbolt.org/z/W8Kx3zYaj):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


auto lines = std::vector<std::string>({
    {R"("ab","cd")"},   // no space between wrappers
    {R"("ab", "cd")"},  // space after comma
    {R"("ab" ,"cd")"},   // space before comma
    {R"("a""b" ,"c"d")"}  // has escaped double-qoutes 
});

auto printChunks(const auto& line, char wrapper) -> void {
    /*
     * looking for end of a field and beginning of next field
     * it should be like
     * example 1          : "ab","cd"
     * double-quoutes     : ↑--↑-↑--↑
     * char index         : 012345678
     * string size        : 123456789
     *
     */

    // Find position of all wrappers (e.g. double-qoutes)
    auto wrapperPositions = std::vector<int>();
    for (auto i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i) {
      if(line[i] == wrapper) {
        wrapperPositions.push_back(i);
      }
    }

    auto chunks = std::vector<std::string>();
    for (auto pos = 0; pos < line.size();) {
        std::cout << line[pos];
      if(line[pos] == wrapper) {
        int nextWrapperPos = line.find("\",", pos); // find closing wrapper
        if(nextWrapperPos not_eq std::string::npos) {
          chunks.push_back(line.substr(pos + 1, nextWrapperPos - pos - 1));
          std::cout << "pos = " << pos 
                    << " nextPos = " << nextWrapperPos <<  std::endl;
          pos += nextWrapperPos;
        } else {
            pos++; 
        }
      }
    }

    for(auto s : chunks) {
        puts(s.c_str());
    }
}

int main() {
    for(auto line : lines) {
        printChunks(line, '"');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting fun fact:  In `for (auto i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i)` `auto i = 0` infers `i` to be an `int`, not an unsigned variable such as will be returned by `line.size()`. I'm a lazy <expletive deleted> so I'd probably use `size_t i = 0` to clean out a bunch of signed-unsigned mismatch warnings the compiler may be kicking out.

Comment: On the other hand, `int nextWrapperPos = line.find("\",", pos);`  is where I'd use `auto`.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, but when `if (line[pos] == wrapper)` isn't entered, nothing advances `pos` and you'll have an infinite loop on your hands.

Comment: Oh. I finally looked at the godbolt link. That's exactly what you're looking for. Recomendation: Paste the output into the question and also add the output you expected so that there's no ambiguity.

Comment: Stepping through the code with a debugger should allow you to find and kill mistakes like that pretty quickly. You'd see that `pos` never moved off of index 6, and a few more steps around the loop and you'd see why.

Comment: I generally handle this sort of stuff with a state machine. When I find a `"`, I enter the `"`-finding state and don't leave it until I find the closing `"`. That'll make sure you don't accidentally exit on a `,`, which is what `int nextWrapperPos = line.find("\",", pos);` looks like it's doing. Lemme take a closer look at that.

Comment: Yeah, You don't want to insert a chunk into `chunks` until you find a `,` that has NOT been wrapped. Currently you end a chunk on `,` or a closing `"`. You need to fix that. As Dúthomhas points out in their answer, how you fix this depends on the sort of behaviour you want. What if you have a token that looks like `   "ab,cd"  ,` Do you want those spaces? Do you just want the stuff in the quotes? What about something that's not easily answered by "trim the whitespace" like `gork"ab,cd"mork,`?

Comment: BTW&JSYK, in CSV parsing, a `"` is only considered special if it is the first non-whitespace character. So `gork"ab,cd"mork,` counts as _two_ fields: `gork"ab` and `cd"mork`. The edge case is `"hello" world,`, which is often just considered as invalid CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, *generalized* CSV parsing is a nightmare with no easy answer. You simply cannot assume anything.

For example, your code assumes that the character sequence `",` is a field delimiter. Unless you can guarantee that as input, then you have made an assumption that will break when input comes as, for example, any of the following:

- `"..." ,`
- `"... \", ...",`
- `"... "", ..."`

And those are just off the top of my head.

(You are also making assumptions about the shape of EOL.)

When writing a CSV parser, you must **first** have an ironclad input format. Only if you can guarantee a specific CSV-like subset can you then apply one-pass reader optimizations.

I have personally found that the most efficient CSV readers do so by reading a file into RAM and performing multiple indexing passes over that.

If the file is too big to fit entirely in RAM, have a pass that simply identifies that part of the file that you are most interested in, read that chunk into RAM, and do your best to make sure that misses/backtracking at the file read level are minimized.

And, as a final note, the most efficient CSV parsing is done by a finite state machine, which is a pain to write by hand. For C++, you might find [Carburetta](https://carburetta.com/) to be a useful tool, though the time you spend learning that one could just as easily be spent planning and coding your own parser. It may also be worth your time perusing code other people have already written to do the same task via [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=c/c+++csv+parsers).

The best place to start is to look at the program(s) producing your CSV data and restrict yourself to what they produce. Some, like Excel, can even be coopted via COM/OCX/ActiveX/whatever-they-call-it-these-days to do the reading for you.

Sorry I can’t give you better news.